# localStorage for a local offline webpage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, storage, offline

I am designing a something like a webapp & want to support "offline" use. It all works except I'm having trouble with the window.localStorage object when accessing the page offline (ie: "file:///page.htm"). From what I researched, this is because localStorage relies on the domain name (for security reasons I assume). Is there a way to use localStorage offline, or an alternative that would allow similar webstorage for offline webpages? I'm designing this for Chrome (& also IE8+, but care more about it working in Chrome).

Comment: short answer: from just an .html file, no. from proprietary solutions like .hta, chrome packaged apps, node-webkit, cordova, yes.

Comment: I think you _can_ get access to arbitrary files on the user's filesystem, but you need to do so through a file handle which is only obtainable through a file picker. In other words, you need to have the user explicitly select _every_ file. Also, I'm not sure I understand what you want to do - is this intended to exist on a server and accessed remotely or is it an offline desktop application written to run through chrome (or a browser in general)?

Comment: I was trying to have the option to avoid the server entirely, and still store some info locally. For example, have the .html on the desktop of your PC or mobile & accessing it directly. localStorage I thought would be the answer, as it allegedly doesn't use the server at all - but apparently it needs the url to have a domain name & file:/// is not a domain name. A local "settings" file in the same directory could work if that's the only way, but I'd rather not choose a settings file every time.

Comment: This may sound crazy & I've never done it, but is it possible to change the innerHTML of the page & then save/overwrite the page itself? There must be some alternative to Storage for a locally accessed page (I hope)!

Comment: @NateDuffy: i have an HTA that saves config in an embeded <script> block at the bottom of the page, using FSO to mode the hta file itself: http://danml.com/netpad.htm . you might also be able to iframe a http url (using an html manifest for offline capability), use it's localStorage, and use postMessage() to talk from file:// to http://